# Negative values for b-vector (RHS) for LP solvers

Tags: linear-programming, lp

Say we have a constraint:

$$x-2y+z \ge 3 \tag{1}$$

Typically to actually solve it, we would need to introduce a surplus variable and an artificial variable:

$$ x-2y+z-s+a=3 \tag{2}$$

However, is it really necessary to maintain a positive right hand side (RHS) and if so why? Yes that's standard form, but I am guessing it's not necessary to solve it computationally.

Why not transform Equation (1) to
$$-x + 2y -z \le -3 \tag{3}, $$
so that we have a positive slack variable coefficient and no artificial variable with
$$-x +2y -z + s =-3 \tag{4}?$$

Do we really need a positive RHS? I don't see the reason other than that's standard form, but how necessary is it to have non-negative b-values/RHS?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about applying the simplex method by hand, there is a problem with what you propose. When solving by hand, you acquire an initial basic feasible solution by using the identity matrix formed by slack and artificial variables and setting the corresponding variables equal to the RHS. In your case, that basis matrix would include the $s$ column, which would be set to -3, an infeasible value. So when solving by hand you do need the artificial variables.

Software solvers do all sorts of preprocessing and might in some cases use either dual simplex or an interior point method from the outset, so I am not 100% sure they would use the two-phase method (which employs those artificial variables). Perhaps someone with experience writing solvers can answer for that case.

Comment: Yeah it makes me wonder if we could start with a solution even if it weren't feasible, and move to feasible points...I guess once you enter feasible region, there is not really a need for simplex to leave feasible region, but I don't see why you have to start with a feasible point. But I guess that would take longer to answer.

Comment: The dual simplex algorithm typically starts with an infeasible (but "superoptimal") solution.

Comment: I don't see a problem with an infeasible starting point perse in regular simplex - if you used artificial variables with bigM in the beginning - wouldn't those variables be driven out of the basis quickly and never re-enter?

Comment: What you are describing is essentially the two phase simplex method: start with a basis including artificial variables, minimize the sum of the artificials (dropping each one as it exits the basis), and when they are all out of the basis then switch to the original objective.